# Templates missing in certain project in Visual Studio 2010 (but not in new)

Tags: vb.net, class, templates, xna

So I have a game project in VS2010 (XNA, win7) that I've been working on for the past 5 years. It's in VB.Net. But when I try to add a new Class to the project today the only templates showing up are C# ones (also I haven't previously added any classes).

When creating new projects I get to choose from all the installed templates (C++, C#, VB.net etc.), but when I'm in my current project I cannot.

I went through all the guides I could find on the issue with solutions such as:
- Using the VS cmd prompt writing:
        - devenv /installvstemplates
        - devenv /resetsettings
- Using the install/repair tool to reinstall the templates
- Checking the folders to ensure they include the templates
- Looking for them in the online templates option (contains nothing).

I'm sure this should be solvable as the templates show up in my new project option, but I can't find any help on the issue.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: So, to confirm, on the solution explorer, you're right-clicking on the project and then tried 'Add New Item'?

Comment: @Steven I go to Project -> add class, or in the Solution explorer rightclicking the project and adding new item yes